# Knex Migration with Docker Compose Psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, knex.js

I have a problem migrating using Knex js inside my docker-compose container.
 the problem is that npm run db (knex migrate:rollback && knex migrate:latest && knex seed:run) would run right before the database is even created. Is there anyway to say that I would only like to run npm run db after the database has been created?

NOTE : if I do this npm commands on the docker terminal after it has been built everything works fine. just fyi

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  #Backend api
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./
    command: npm run db
    working_dir: /user/src/server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/user/src/server
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://test:test@192.168.99.100:5432/interapp
    links:
      - postgres

  # PostgreSQL database
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: interapp
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

and here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.14.0

WORKDIR /user/src/server

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the docker-compose.yml file, using sh (bash) for a contained environment context for your command to run in. ie. sh -c 'npm run db'
your docker-compose file would now be
secondly, use the depends_on step to wait for the database to start

```
services:
  #Backend api
    server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./
    command: sh -c 'npm run db'
    working_dir: /user/src/server
  depends_on:
    -postgres
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - ./:/user/src/server
  environment:
    POSTGRES_URI: postgres://test:test@192.168.99.100:5432/interapp
  links:
    - postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) to server service should do the trick here.

```
services:
    server:
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        ...
```

This will cause docker-compose to start postgres container before the server container. It will not however wait for postgres to be ready. In this case it shouldn't be problem, because postgres starts really quickly.

If you want something more solid, or `depends_on` doesn't do the trick, you can add entrypoint wrapping script to your container. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/, where you can read more about it. There are also links to tools, so you don't have to write your own script from scratch.